# Importing empty FoxPro date fields into SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, date, import, null, visual-foxpro

I'm in the process of migrating a FoxPro-based system into a SQL Server 2005 database.  In the FoxPro system, date fields without values show as '  /  /    '.  When I use the SQL Server Import/Export Wizard, these empty date fields get translated to '12/30/1899 12:00:00 AM' in the resulting SQL Server table.

My question is: what is the easiest way to have SQL Server translate these empty date fields to a NULL rather than the 1899 date?  I've had no luck in digging around the Import/Export Wizard, and I don't have enough experience with SSIS packages to know if anything in that avenue would suit my needs.

I'll be importing a number of tables at different times, so the easier and more repeatable the solution, the better.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I appreciate both the suggestions offered, I ended up finding more of a "one and done" solution, rather than running a query on each table after I import them.

I ended up creating an SSIS package and inserting a derived column transformation between the source and destination as needed.

For example, in the Derived Column Transformation Editor, if I had a date column called 'comp_date', and I can say with certainty that any date before 1910 is not valid, my first few columns in the Editor look something like this:

```
Derived Column Name     Derived Column        Expression
-------------------     --------------        -----------------------------------------
comp_date               Replace 'comp_date'   DATEPART("year",comp_date) < 1910 ? NULL(DT_DATE):comp_date
```

This way, I only need to account for the null conversion once when I configure it in the package, then continuously add to the package as more tables get thrown into the mix.  This gets me exactly the results I need.  Thanks again for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I'd leave them as the 1899 date and treat that as an empty date in your code. It's usually a better approach than faffing with inserting null datetimes.

Answer (score 0):

If the value 1899-12-30T00:00:00 is never to be expected in a column you can update the value after the insert.

```
update YourTable
set DateColumn = null
where DateColumn = '1899-12-30T00:00:00'
```